# I am not able to install ruby through rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am not able to install ruby via rvm. I uninstalled all the homebrew, rvm and installed again.

After installing rvm I am not able to install ruby via it.

```
rvm install ruby 2.2.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.


Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/log/1566152593_ruby-2.2.3: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/1566152593_ruby-2.2.3/update_system.log: No such file or directory
Updating system......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.2.3',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1566152593_ruby-2.2.3/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I didnt get any solution after searching internet for an hour

Comment: How did you install RVM? It should not be at `/usr/local/rvm`, which is probably the issue. Make sure you install RVM using [the instructions on their site](https://rvm.io) -- `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` -- not using brew.

Answer (score 1):

As reading from the documentation [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/help/fix-permissions.md)

You can try

```
rvm fix-permissions
```